# Format statement with unknown columns

Tags: format, fortran

I am attempting to use fortran to write out a comma-delimited file for import into another commercial package.  The issue is that I have an unknown number of data columns.  My output needs to look like this:

```
a_string,a_float,a_different_float,float_array_elem1,float_array_elem2,...,float_array_elemn
```

which would result in something that might look like this:

```
L1080,546876.23,4325678.21,300.2,150.125,...,0.125
L1090,563245.1,2356345.21,27.1245,...,0.00983
```

I have three issues.  One, I would prefer the elements to be tightly grouped (variable column width), two, I do not know how to define a variable number of array elements in the format statement, and three, the array elements can span a large range--maybe 12 orders of magnitude.  The following code conceptually does what I want, but the variable 'n' and the lack of column-width definition throws an error (of course):

```
WRITE(50,900) linenames(ii),loc(ii,1:2),recon(ii,1:n)
900 FORMAT(A,',',F,',',F,n(',',F))
```

(I should note that n is fixed at run-time.)  The write statement does what I want it to when I do WRITE(50,*), except that it's width-delimited.

I think this thread almost answered my question, but I got quite confused: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751453/matlabs-fortrans-format-equivalents/2751615#2751615).  Right now I have a shell script with awk fixing the issue, but that solution is...inelegant.  I could do some manipulation to make the output a string, and then just write it, but I would rather like to avoid that option if at all possible.

I'm doing this in Fortran 90 but I like to try to keep my code as backwards-compatible as possible.

Comment: I should also note that the reason I would like tight columns is twofold: one, that is the desired input to the next program, and two, size.  There might be several million lines in the resultant output file, with many dozens of columns.  Spaces make a difference!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the format close to what you want is f0.3, this will give no spaces and a fixed number of decimal places.   I think if you want to also lop off trailing zeros you'll need to do a good bit of work.

The 'n' in your write statement can be larger than the number of data values, so one (old school) approach is to put a big number there, eg 100000.  Modern fortran does have some syntax to specify indefinite repeat, i'm sure someone will offer that up.

----edit
the unlimited repeat is as you might guess an asterisk..and is evideltly "brand new" in f2008

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that no space occurs between the entries in your line, you can write them separately in character variables and then print them out using the`adjustl()` function in fortran:

```
program csv
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
  integer, parameter :: nn = 3
  real(dp), parameter :: floatarray(nn) = [ -1.0_dp, -2.0_dp, -3.0_dp ]
  integer :: ii
  character(30) :: buffer(nn+2), myformat

  ! Create format string with appropriate number of fields.
  write(myformat, "(A,I0,A)") "(A,", nn + 2, "(',',A))"
  ! You should execute the following lines in a loop for every line you want to output
  write(buffer(1), "(F20.2)") 1.0_dp  ! a_float
  write(buffer(2), "(F20.2)") 2.0_dp  ! a_different_float
  do ii = 1, nn
    write(buffer(2+ii), "(F20.3)") floatarray(ii)
  end do
  write(*, myformat) "a_string", (trim(adjustl(buffer(ii))), ii = 1, nn + 2)

end program csv
```

The demonstration above is only for one output line, but you can easily write a loop around the appropriate block to execute it for all your output lines. Also, you can choose different numerical format for the different entries, if you wish.

Comment: once here you can readily go one more step and strip trailing zeros (probly write a simple trim-like function that trims space or 0.)